# PHP randomly printing code within php tags

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session-variables

I wrote some PHP/sql with the intention of storing session variables into a SQL table. (I left out some html that tells the user that the php worked.)

```
<?php
session_start();
$name = $_REQUEST["name"];
$type = $_REQUEST["type"];
$lengthnum = $_REQUEST["lengthnum"];
$rewardnum = $_REQUEST["rewardnum"];
$itemreward = $_REQUEST["itemreward"];

$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxxxxxx";
$pw = "xxxxxxxx";
$options = array(PDO ::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO ::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try
{
    $my_pdo = new PDO ($dsn, $username, $pw, $options);
    $sql_stmt = "INSERT INTO xxxxxx (Name, Type, Length, Reward, Item)
                 VALUES ($name, $type, $lengthnum, $rewardnum, $itemreward)";
    $my_pdo->query($sql_stmt);
}
catch(Exception $a)
{
    echo "<p>Error..." . $a->getMessage() . "</p>";
}
?>
```

For some reason this code "breaks" out of the php tags after "$options = array(" and this is output to the html file.

```
PDO ::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); try { $my_pdo = new PDO ($dsn, $username, $pw, $options); $sql_stmt = "INSERT INTO simpleWFA (Name, Type, Length, Reward, Item) VALUES ($name, $type, $lengthnum, $rewardnum, $itemreward)"; $my_pdo->query($sql_stmt); } catch(Exception $a) { echo "

Error..." . $a->getMessage() . "
"; } ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would say you are slightly abusing the way how you should be codding in PDO/PHP. It is completely unconventional and not on par with common practices

Comment: I have it working in another project, that uses the exact same layout. How would I do this the "correct" way?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but I'd say your array definition is invalid.

```
$options = array(PDO ::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO ::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

should be something like

```
$options = array("PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE"=>"PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION");
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to be the issue, changing it to what you have doesn't fix the problem and I have used this pdo array before successfully.

Comment: No, I fixed those right after I posted and it didn't help. It might be my IDE, PHP Coder is pretty terrible and I cant test the code on a live server yet.